# Setting up Xcode to work with Arduino

Tags: xcode, arduino

I have read a number of forums posts and blog "tutorials" and all of the contain comments that they are out of date or don't work.

How does one setup Xcode to work with Arduino, installing a template etc ?

Has anyone been successful with this ?

Comment: i've done it by creating my own Makefile and linking it to Xcode via target makefile execution. I can clean, compile and upload my code in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People are starting to get there. I've had the same problem for the longest time and I've finally managed to get it to work on XCode 3.2

See here for Project Templates for XCode3.2: https://github.com/timknapen/Arduino-With-XCode
And here for Project Templates for XCode4: http://sites.google.com/site/vilorei/arduino/20--arduino-makefile-for-xcode/20b--xcode-4

I haven't tested the XCode4 project templates myself.

Comment: The project has been updated on Github. It now works and has been tested with XCode4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a makefile to build arduino code and call that makefile from xcode examples being here
http://mjo.tc/atelier/2009/02/arduino-cli.html
and
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arduino

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

New and improve Xcode project for Arduino and chipKIT, **mpideXcode** now with code-sense and click-to-error and other niceties! For a template, check **embedXcode**. As at today, both support Arduino 0023, Arduino 1.0, chipKIT 0023. Wiring 1.0 is on the pipes.

Check [documentation](http://sites.google.com/site/vilorei/arduino/20--arduino-makefile-for-xcode) and [code](https://github.com/rei-vilo/mpideXcode)

Xcode specialists are welcomed!